# Linking to my apps on the App Store

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

I want to create button that, when pressed, takes the user into the App Store and all my apps are shown.

At the moment the code is

```
-(IBAction)goReviewTwo:(id)sender; {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.com/apps/lifevisionstudios"]];
}
```

But that doesn't work. Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: You shouldn't delete your question when you figure it out - answer the question below and accept it yourself!

Comment: See my answer below for a better way to link.

Comment: Matthew Frederick and zpasternack ways, are the way to go, but remember that it will not show anything in simulator because there is no appstore in it. You need to test it in a real device.

Answer (score 3):

Your URL isn't correct. Apple's [**iTunes Link Maker**](http://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker/) is the easiest and best way to get the authoritative link to your apps, including for App Stores in various countries.

You can also get a link to a page with all of your company's apps the same way, which seems to be what you're looking for. In the Link Maker your company is referred to as the *Artist*.

Lastly, rather than using `http` you should use `itms`, which will send the user directly to the App Store app rather than routing them through a blank Mobile Safari page first:

```
itms://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/appname/id?uo=4
```

***Edited to add***

As noted in **Rab**'s answer, if you remove the `/us` it should automatically go to the user's local App Store. It turns out that you also need to remove the query string (`?uo=4`) that iTunes and the Link Maker generate:

```
itms://itunes.apple.com/artist/appname/
```

Comment: As a weird aside, it gives me a different looking query string and I don't have to remove it (edit: if I'm navigating to a single app that is). Good to know about the query string at the end. So far I haven't had to remove it, but I have just been testing the http:// version.

Comment: Wow, weird to see that someone put their app in my links.

Answer (score 1):

Just find that page in iTunes, right click the link and choose "Copy Link".  Paste it into your code.  In your case, I think it would be:

```
-(IBAction)goReviewTwo:(id)sender
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/lifevision-studios/id415139916"]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That should look like itms://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/your-name-here/id101010101 . That's your artist page, and shows your various apps. Take off the /us/ and it should choose based on the user's location. Use the link maker mentioned earlier to specify another country's app store (it will swap in /kr/ for Korea, etc.).

Comment: Removing the `us/` doesn't seem to work, iTunes complains about an invalid link. I'd love to find a way to make it international.

Comment: That's too bad.. I can take the /us off of mine if I'm using a browser and it will work: http://itunes.apple.com/artist/elemental-art-technology/id371878331 . Does it work for you in a browser but not with itms:// ?

Comment: @Rab Ah, removing the query string does the trick! Excellent!

Comment: @Rab Unfortunately the same doesn't seem to work for a single app

Comment: @Matthew are you sure? I can take http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pluckies/id378689110?mt=8 and remove /us, and http://itunes.apple.com/app/pluckies/id378689110?mt=8 still brings me to the app store.

Comment: @Rab Aw man, so in *that* case you have to **leave the query string**. man oh man, so crazy.

Answer (score 0):

You can link to the App Store with a specific query, like your iTunes Name.

This works:

```
NSURL *appStoreUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZSearch.woa/wa/search?media=software&submit=media&term=Anoxy%20Software"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:appStoreUrl];
```